# What kind of bread crumbs is being used here? (picture and video)

Tags: breadcrumbs

I am trying to make Gordon Ramsay's Bloody Mary Linguine. The [recipe here](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/home/you/article-2418913/Food-special-Bloody-Mary-linguine.html) has a nice close up picture of the finished product. There are big pieces of white bread crumbs, fried to golden brown in a pan. [In his video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zhK4HF_oRho&feature=youtu.be&t=1m54s), he pours out a big fluffy pieces of white bread crumbs from a jar.

What kind of bread crumb is this? I went out and bought a bottle of "plain bread crumbs" but it turned out to be very fine, sand-like crumbs that [looked like this](http://honeyandspice.files.wordpress.com/2011/07/golden-breadcrumbs.jpg). I understand that the color comes from the brown crust, but what about the texture?

Because the crumbs are too fine and sand-like, it seems pointless cooking them like what the recipe recommends. What kind of crumb would give me the same texture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [his book](http://books.google.ca/books?id=bKlx9OprVEUC&pg=PT368&lpg=PT368&dq=gordon%20ramsay%20bloody%20mary%20linguine%20recipe&source=bl&ots=yawcbmfCxU&sig=4iCv1QXH_rBYefFsL2-BcxoEaTs&hl=en&sa=X&ei=rNWvUv-7OY_zoASDhICACg&ved=0CFYQ6AEwBTgK#v=onepage&q=gordon%20ramsay%20bloody%20mary%20linguine%20recipe&f=false), he specifies just "white breadcrumbs".

If you're having trouble finding some, you could look for panko style bread crumbs. [This is the brand](http://www.kikkomanusa.com/homecooks/products/products_hc_details.php?pf=10518) that's available around here, but your mileage may vary. It's a larger Asian style breadcrumb made without the crusts. It gives it a lighter texture. I suspect that is a lot closer to what he's using in the video.

Comment: I suspect these are *fresh* breadcrumbs, made from processing bread which is stale or perhaps day old, but not completely dried out.

Comment: I guess he is using fresh, self-made breadcrumbs. But Panko breadcrumbs close to the look. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I would be very surprised if he bought ready-made bread crumbs.

What would be normal in this part of the world (and indeed, what it looks like in the video) is to just get a normal white loaf (ie. sliced bread for making sandwiches) and whizz it in a food processor. This way also allows you to get whatever size crumb you desire.